# Latex, display a long image in multiple page?

Tags: image, tex

(Please don't move my post to Tex, I can't post image there.)
I have a long UML diagram, I use the following code.
The figure is about two and a half page long, but only the first page is showing, and the lower part of the figure is missing. How do I display the whole diagram in multiple page?

Exactly what code should I add?

```
\usepackage{graphicx} 
......
\includegraphics[height= 81.3cm, width=18cm]{myImage.png}
\captionof{figure}{Sequence Diagram}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `viewport` option of `\includegraphics` to display a specific portion of the image. By using this command three times you can display your image in three portions.

The `viewport` option takes 4 arguments:

- The first two values are the (x,y) coordinates (in pixels) of the lower left corner of the portion of the image file you want to include.
- The second two values are the coordinates of the upper right corner.

For example, the command `\includegraphics*[viewport=0 0 100 100]{myImage.png}` would display the bottom-left corner of the image. Note that you need the `*` in order to actually crop the image; otherwise it will only be shifted.

Comment: It doesnt work to enable a large image span multiple page, its merely cropping it